# emulate fabric/capistrano with puppet or chef

Tags: deployment, puppet, chef, capistrano, fabric

i have a few remote environments where i can only connect from outside but not from inside to outside. for my deployments/configuration needs i used fabric and capistrano that works fine but I have pressure to use a complete configuration system as puppet or chef.

is there a way i can push specific commands via puppet or chef ? (please keep in mind that the remote hosts can not connect to my site where i would have the puppet/chef server)

thanks

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I don't use Chef and I'm not very familiar with it, but a former co-worker of mine told me once that one thing he appreciated on Chef over Puppet was that you could, from the command line, tell it to run a command over a number of machines. From the way he told me, it was with `chef` itself you did it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mcollective](http://www.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/) to run remote commands. You have to install a client on each puppet client though.
Note that mcollective also requires an activemq server.

Comment: does mcollective needs an activemq server (this is what is written into their getting started) ?

Comment: yes you do need one for mcollective to run

Comment: it is bundled as part of puppet-enterprise; you can grab a demo with 10 nodes without a needing to purchase a license.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of reviving an old thread, check out [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/docs/gettingstarted.html#your-first-commands) for running arbitrary commands over a set of hosts.  Set up a hosts file with a group named "all" and then type `ansible all -a "/bin/echo hello"` to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Chef has a "deploy" resource that can be used to do a fabric/capistrano style of deployment. It is documented here with examples:

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource

Guides for more sophisticated fully automated setup and deployment can be found on the Opscode knowledge base.

http://help.opscode.com/kb/otherhelp

Django and Rails application deployment examples are used.